# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar un solo elemento en un Select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola quisiera mostrar solamente el primer elemento de este select y ocultar los demás para luego ir mostrandolos cuando vaya seleccionando la opcion anterior del select; es decir si mi primera opcion del select es primero, cuando lo seleccione quiero que se haga visible segundo:

```
<select class="chosen-select form-control" name="grados" id="grados" data-placeholder="Seleccione el grado...">
    <option value=""> Seleccione el grado...</option>
        @foreach($grados as $ciuda)
          <option value="{{ $ciuda->id }}"> {{ $ciuda->nom_grado }} </option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: pon el el primer option "`selected`" y asi te aparecera seleccionado...

Comment: En vez de mostrar el array que tiene todos los elementos, copia el primer elemento en otro array y visualizarlo. Cuando haga click en el primer elemento del select, incluye en tu array el segundo y así sucesivamente.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno nada mas crea un option normal y los demás ponle:

```
<option value="{{ $ciuda->id }}" style="display: none;"> {{ $ciuda->nom_grado }} </option>
```

Y le pones un id para después mostrarlo.